# Повторение рандомного числа в PHP

Tags: php, случайные-числа

`$random = rand(1,6)`
Проверить сколько раз повторяется каждое число.

Comment: и что получилось?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Не совсем понятно чего конкретно вы хотите, Андрей! При распечатке переменной $random и обновлении страницы у вас будет появляться цифра в диапазоне от 1го до 6ти включительно. Что бы вы хотели тут проверить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, какой вопрос, такой и ответ)))

```
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++){
    $random = rand(1,6);
    $counter[$random]++;
}
print_r($counter);
```

В результате имеем `$counter[сгенерированное_число] => количество_повторений`

```
Array
(
    [6] => 9
    [4] => 16
    [2] => 22
    [5] => 19
    [3] => 15
    [1] => 19
)
```

Естественно, при каждом запуске буду разные данные

Comment: Спасибо большое, такой ответ был нужен.